# Could two benders of different nations have a child could it inherit both abilities?

Tags: avatar-the-last-airbender, the-legend-of-korra

Is it possible for two benders to have a child who could wield both abilities of its parents?

Comment: Only the Avatar, master of all elements, can bend more than one element.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Would it be possible for some to bend two elements?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/16699/would-it-be-possible-for-some-to-bend-two-elements)

Answer (score 3):

No. In order for an individual to hold more than one element, he/she needs Raava to hold it for him/her, as we learn in season 2, episode 8: *Beginnings, Part 2*

Also, we saw a couple of examples where parents from different nations had children who could only bend one element:

- Mako and Bolin's father was from the earth nation and their mother from the fire nation. Each one of them could only bend one element.
- Aang and Katara's children could only bend one element- water or air.

Comment: In the case of Bolin, there is a small theory that he could bend Lava because of his Fire bending mother, and that would be the reason he could not bend metal (needing to be pure earth bender (?) ). That could say that the bending abilities are related to our genes, and explains why all benders are not equals.

Answer (score 0):

As [Mor Zamir's answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/227634/85712) states, no one can bend more than one element, and the only reason the Avatar can do it is because of the spirit Raava.

However, as [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/194473/85712) speculates, it might be that certain specialised forms of bending may be possible due to having heritage of different nations; specifically that [lavabending](https://avatar.fandom.com/wiki/Lavabending) might only be possible for a child of an earthbender and a firebender (such as [Bolin](https://avatar.fandom.com/wiki/Bolin)).

The Avatar Wiki page on [lavabending](https://avatar.fandom.com/wiki/Lavabending) has as it's first Trivia point:

> - *[Avatar Extras](https://avatar.fandom.com/wiki/Avatar_Extras_(Book_Two:_Earth))* for ["The Avatar State"](https://avatar.fandom.com/wiki/Avatar_Extras_(Book_Two:_Earth)#.22The_Avatar_State.22) stated that lavabending was a combination of earthbending and [firebending](https://avatar.fandom.com/wiki/Firebending) and thus something that only the Avatar could accomplish. [Book Three: Change](https://avatar.fandom.com/wiki/Book_Three:_Change) rectified this and revealed lavabending to be a rare specialized technique of earthbending.

Following that second link, we find this quote:

> 112. [Lava bending](https://avatar.fandom.com/wiki/Lavabending) is a combination of earthbending and firebending.

So it would appear that lavabending likely does require a firebending and earthbending parent.

However evidence thus far has shown that only someone who is primarily an earthbender can perform lavabending (firebenders cannot do it), so it is still the case that someone with earth and fire heritage can still only be either an earthbender or a firebender.

Comment: Please don't answer a question if you're also voting/flagging to close it. If you're doing so you're doing as such because you think it shouldn't be answered. The fact that you flagged to close as a dupe means you should be able to answer the dupe with this answer instead.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot Sorry, I probably should have picked one or the other...

Comment: That said, there are a _lot_ of downvoted answers in that [other question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/16699/would-it-be-possible-for-some-to-bend-two-elements) (mostly from users with 1 rep) that need cleaning up; I'm not sure I'd have wanted to throw my own answer into that mess...